# Azure Devops grant user permissions to manage teams

Tags: azure-devops

I want to give our devs the ability to grant repo access without making them full admins.  We have a team "Partners" set up that grants repo access. What permissions do I need to assign to our devs to enable them to add people to the Partners team?

Comment: This question can be answered by looking up the documentation. Please do research before just posting questions on here.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/about-permissions?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you could set the [team administrator role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/about-permissions?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#role-based-permissions) to the devs to manage the "Partners" team. And set the [contributors permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/set-git-repository-permissions?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Forganizations%2Fsecurity%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Forganizations%2Fsecurity%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops#default-repository-permissions) of the repo to the team to manage aceess of the repo without making them full admins.